help with understanding datasheet for ADS8681
I'm a chemical/materials engineering student and I've taken one basic (like, V=IR) circuits class; I'm in way over my head here with this electrical stuff
I want to use an ADS 8681 on my PCB. I'm having trouble understanding what to connect where. I've got the output from my sensor connected to the AIN_P pin and the negative pin of my sensor connected to the AIN_GND pin. I've got the capacitors between REFIO and REFGND and between REFCAP and REFGND.

I'm not sure about the rest. Do I just connect AVDD and DVDD to my 5 V net? The datasheet says something about capacitors for those pins, too:

Power sources to the ADS868x must be clean and well-bypassed. Using a 1-μF, X7R-grade, 0603-size
ceramic capacitor with at least a 10-V rating in close proximity to the analog (AVDD) supply pins is
recommended. For decoupling the digital supply pin (DVDD), a 1-μF, X7R-grade, 0603-size ceramic capacitor
with at least a 10-V rating is recommended.

Do those capacitors go between AVDD/DVDD and ground then? or between AVDD/DVDD and 5V?

Yes, AVDD and DVDD get connected to +5V. The capacitors should go between those pins and GND, preferably close to the IC. These capacitors are used to improve the Power Supply Rejection Ratio performance, which is an important concept to learn but might require several layers of research for you.You'll notice the datasheet recommends decoupling AIN_P and AIN_GND so make sure you do your due diligence there. Also make sure you read through the RESET pin functionality and make sure you have the necessary control over it for your application, whether that's a simple pull-up to keep it high or designing for control of it to toggle low and high. BTW, what's your application? If you're just trying to get analog voltage readings from a simple sensor, this ADC is probably overkill.

Decoupling is not there to stabilize the supply voltage, and is absolutely necessary for reliable operation no matter the cleanliness of the supply

@MrGerber True, I will update my answer accordingly.

thanks for the help!!
how do I decouple AIN_P and AIN_GND? I couldn't find what capacitance value I should have. maybe I missed it or there's some way I'm supposed to calculate this?
It's for a research project and we need 1 M sps and 16-bit resolution. this was one of the only ADCs I could find that met those requirements without needing me to make some input/reference driver circuit that looked super complicated and I would for sure screw up
